# Update gradle ndk in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I try to use `EasyAr` library for build an augmented reality application for android. i follow [Import EasyAr Android SDK](https://www.easyar.com/doc_sdk/en/Getting-Started/Setting-up-EasyAR-Android-SDK.html) tutorial but problem is  `ndk` part make error. Also i add `jniLibrary` files to `jniLibs` folder and remove `android.source` part.

My app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    ... -> Default configuration

    ndk{
        moduleName "HelloARNative"
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../../../easyAr/include")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        stl = "gnustl_static"
        ldLibs.add("log")
        ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
    }
}

dependencies {
    ... -> Some dependencies
}
```

**EDIT1**:
Error massage:

```
Error:(19, 0) Could not find method ndk() for arguments [build_35mhq15314xxy8foo9ao90j63$_run_closure1$_closure5@793f61be] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
<a href="openFile:/Users/saman/Downloads/ARtoolkit/AndroidStudioProjects/EasyArProject/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: check this https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781849691505/1/ch01lvl1sec12/updating-android-ndk

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: @KostasDrak , Please see my question again. i add error massage in Edit1 part.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is based in the *experimental* gradle plugin for Android NDK. Nowadays, it is recommended to use the stable plugin instead. This involves writing **Android.mk** or **cmake script**. Google has published [these instructions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable). The time is ripe for EasyAr to update their tutorial, too.